# Prolog issue with and & or symbol

Tags: date, prolog, rule

I have a few facts which are as follows

```
letter(monica, suzane, '2012-02-13').
letter(suzane, janet, '2012-02-14').
letter(suzane, monica, '2012-02-14').
letter(tom, phillip, '2012-02-14').
letter(phillip, suzane, '2012-02-14').
letter(monica, phillip, '2012-02-15').
```

I want to create a rule that returns the names of all the people who exchanged a letter to both X and Y, before the specified date. For example, if X is monica and Y is suzane and D is 2012-02-16, then it should only return phillip because both monica and suzane exchanged a letter with phillip.

Currently, I have this rule;

```
letterexch(X,Y,D):-
((  ( letter(X, Z, D1); letter(Z, X, D1) ), \+ Z = Y);
 (  ( letter(Y, Z, D1); letter(Z, Y, D1) ), \+ Z = X)), D1 @<D, nl, print(Z),false.
```

I think the or symbol (;) after '+ Z = Y)' should be an and (,) symbol rather than an or symbol (;) but when I set the rule with an and symbol (,) and query it as follows:

```
?- letterexch(monica, suzane, '2012-02-16').
```

i get:

```
false
```

but if I set the rule like the above with an or symbol (;) and query it as follows:

```
?- letterexch(monica, suzane, '2012-02-16').
```

i get:

```
phillip
janet
phillip
```

However, I only need phillip to be printed. (I don't mind if phillip is duplicated because I know how to get rid of it later).

Therefore, I need to know why when the and symbol (,) is used, I get false rather than phillip printed twice.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whether it's "and" or "or" is a matter of the logic that makes sense in the context. In this case, your expression `( letter(X, Z, D1); letter(X, Z, D1) )` should be `( letter(X, Z, D1); letter(Z, X, D1) )`, and the "or" is correct unless you want to require that the `letter` relation between X and Z is bidirectional.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's "and" or "or" is a matter of the logic that makes sense in the context. In this case, your expression

```
( letter(X, Z, D1); letter(X, Z, D1) )
```

should be

```
( letter(X, Z, D1); letter(Z, X, D1) )
```

The OR means that you want the expression to succeed if EITHER `X` has a letter to `Z`, OR if `Z` has a letter to `X`. If you use AND, then you mean that you want it to succeed ONLY if there is a letter going in both directions (`X` to `Z` AND `Z` to `Y`). If that's what you really mean, then use "and" (`,`).

Going to the bigger expression:

```
(  ( letter(X, Z, D1); letter(X, Z, D1) ), \+ Z = Y) ;
(  ( letter(Y, Z, D1); letter(Y, Z, D1) ), \+ Z = X))
```

In this case, you really are looking for AND, not OR since you want BOTH sets of transactions to be true simultaneously. The other issue is that you probably don't want to stipulate the same date across both sets of exchanges (`D1`). You probably want to express this as:

```
letterexch(X,Y,D):-
    (letter(X, Z, D1); letter(Z, X, D1)),  % look for exch 'twixt X Z on date D1
    (letter(Y, Z, D2); letter(Z, Y, D2)),  % look for exch 'twixt Y Z on date D2
    \+ Z = Y,
    \+ Z = X,
    print(Z), nl,
    false.
```

If you run this, you get:

```
| ?- letterexch(monica, suzane, '2012-02-16').
phillip

no
```

One solution. I did leave `D` as a singleton, and I offer it as an exercise to determine how to handle `D`.

---

**ADDENDUM**

When working on a problem like this, the convenient thing about Prolog is you can hand-type the pieces in as a debug tool to figure out what to expect. For instance, if you enter:

```
| ?- (letter(monica, Z, D1); letter(Z, monica, D1)).

D1 = '2012-02-13'
Z = suzane ? a

D1 = '2012-02-15'
Z = phillip

D1 = '2012-02-14'
Z = suzane

(1 ms) no
```

And then similarly for `suzane`:

```
| ?- (letter(suzane, Z, D2); letter(Z, suzane, D2)).

D2 = '2012-02-14'
Z = janet ? a

D2 = '2012-02-14'
Z = monica

D2 = '2012-02-13'
Z = monica

D2 = '2012-02-14'
Z = phillip

(1 ms) no
```

And then combine them:

```
| ?-  (letter(monica, Z, D1); letter(Z, monica, D1)),
      (letter(suzane, Z, D2); letter(Z, suzane, D2)).

D1 = '2012-02-15'
D2 = '2012-02-14'
Z = phillip ? a
```

You can watch the pieces come together and resolve issues as you go.

Comment: I made a typo in the rule which you pointed out. This is my actual rule:letterexch(X,Y,D):-
((  ( letter(X, Z, D1); letter(Z, X, D1) ), \+ Z = Y);
 (  ( letter(Y, Z, D1); letter(Z, Y, D1) ), \+ Z = X)), D1 @<D, nl, print(Z),false.

Comment: I also tried the rule you told me about but it doesn't work it just gives me false

Comment: @user3182311, that's because the rules that I copied from your original clause state that the date must always be `D1`. To fix that, we need to make the date of the second statement `D2` so it's not enforced as the same. See the update. But then you need to decide: what do you want to compare `D` against?

Comment: I tried what you told me to do and it works. I think the main problem was that I had two D1s rather than D1 and D2. Thanks you so much and thanks for the advice